# SQL Поиск строк с отличиями между дублями по одному условию

Tags: sql

Ребята, подскажите как составить запрос, уже всю голову словала=(
Есть таблица `table_A` на 100 тысяч записей

Столбцы:

```
table_A.numOrder
table_A.count
```

В table_A.numOrder находятся дублированные номера заказов(всего 100 тысяч записей и из них только 50 тысяч уникальные)

Может быть ситуация 1:

```
table_A.numOrder = TDR140142
table_A.numOrder = TDR140142
table_A.count = 2500
table_A.count = 2500
```

и ситуация 2:

```
table_A.numOrder = TDR140138
table_A.numOrder = TDR140138
table_A.count = 642541
table_A.count = 239754,1
```

как из таблицы выцепить записи в которых возникла ситуация 2 (в двух дублях `table_A.numOrder` разные суммы `table_A.count`)?

Answer (score 0):

Если mssql можно попробовать так:

```
/*Создаю временную таблицу для проверки*/
Declare @table_A table (numOrder varchar(max),[count] numeric(12,2))
insert into @table_A 
values ('TDR140142',2500),('TDR140142',2500),('TDR140138',642541),('TDR140138',239754.1)
        ,('TDR140141',2501),('TDR140141',2501),('TDR140138',56.12),('TDR140139',41.1)
        ,('TDR140139',25),('TDR140139',500),('TDR140139',64.00),('TDR140139',20.1)

/*Присваиваем уникальный ID каждой строчке*/
;with cte as (
select ROW_NUMBER () over  (order by numOrder ) as id,*
from @table_A)
/*Далее уже связываем получившуюся таблицу с собой же по numOrder,
 но так, чтобы не были равны ID(так мы исключим кучу дублей) и 
count(так мы как-раз и найдем с одинаковым номером но разной суммой).  */
select distinct ct.* 
from cte ct
    inner join cte ctt on ct.numOrder=ctt.numOrder
where ct.id<>ctt.id and ct.count<>ctt.count
```

Создание CTE и добавление ID тут нужно для того, чтобы отсечь дублирующие значения.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]